# How to print all dates between two days in R?

Tags: r, date

I need to write a code in R that will print all dates between 04-12-2020 and today. I've tried googling it and I'm not really sure how to start. Dates need to be in mm-dd-yyyy format.

Comment: Just parse the dates (i.e. via `as.Date()`) and feed them into `seq()`.  Lots of answers for this type of problem.

Answer (score 3):

We can convert to `Date` class with `mdy` from `lubridate` and use `seq`, while specifying the `by` as '1 day'

```
library(lubridate)
seq(mdy('04-12-2020'), today(), by = '1 day')
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it didn't return any output in the console, just the + sign on the next line. Is there something else i need to do to get it to print all the dates?

Comment: @0427092 sorry, wrong bracket didn't close. updated

Comment: now it's not giving the + on the next line anymore, but it's still not returning anything in the output. If I try to run it with the cursor on the end of the last line you gave it says "Error in mdy("04-12-2020") : could not find function "mdy"". do I need to download another package?

Comment: @0427092 i showed `library(lubridate)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (I don't know why it didn't work when I wrote it on the first line of code, but when I checked the box in "packages" it worked.)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed on this that it's coming out with the format yyyy-mm-dd even though my code says seq(mdy('04-12-2020'). Is there a way to get the output into mm-dd-yyyy format?